# Quasar q-scroll-area и q-virtual-scroll

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

Здраствуйте, может кто объяснить в чем разница между q-scroll-area и q-virtual-scroll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**q-scroll-area**

Это элемент в котором все сразу отрендерено и запихать туда можно всё, что угодно.
Ну т.е. вообще всё.

**q-virtual-scroll**

Рендерит только то, что в данный момент должно быть показано пользователю. Идеален в случае если у вас массив из 10000 элементов и вы не хотите заставлять браузер пользователя отрисовывать их все сразу. Причем можно как пихнуть эти 10000 элементов в дату сразу, так и подгружать их с API по мере надобности и только те, где сейчас находится прокрутка.

Вот в этом примере хорошо видно, как отрисовка проходит после прокрутки (тут они эмулируют задержку обращения к апишке через setTimeout)
https://quasar.dev/vue-components/virtual-scroll#Example--Generate-items-on-the-fly